# Equal height columns with jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've tried numerous approaches to getting equal columns, and none have worked for me. I've tried every variation of jQuery plugin that I could find with different calls using both document ready and window load, in head and before the end of body... just no luck... the sidebar will not continue to meet my content.

I've created a fiddle with my latest shot (which is this method: http://www.outsidethebracket.com/equal-height-columns/), but am up for changing to whichever method will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WraW/

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#sidebar").height(Math.max($("#content").height(),$("#sidebar").height()));
})
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You ought to set the height of `#content` as well as `#sidebar`

Comment: Try `$("#sidebar,#content").height(Math.max($("#content").height(),$("#sidebar").height()));`

Comment: working for me : http://jsfiddle.net/7WraW/3/

Comment: Try <table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>

Comment: you don't need to wrap it in window.load as it's already the default in jsfiddle. Otherwise works fine.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using JavaScript to do this when equal height columns can be achieved with pure CSS (and not an excessive amount like the article you link to claims)?

Comment: @cimmanon I tried using just CSS and that didn't work for me either... I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

Works fine if you use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hgt = Math.max($("#content").height(), $("#sidebar").height());
    $("#sidebar,#content").height(hgt);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7WraW/5/

Comment: This is clearly working in the fiddle, I see it with my own eyes, yet when I put it into my own code and try viewing the page in my browser it still does not work. No wonder I've been banging my head against a wall, not sure what's wrong...

Comment: Okay, I downloaded the jQuery library locally instead of using Google and works on content-filled pages, but not for pages with content filling them. I have container set to min-height: 100%, and the container does reach the bottom of the page no matter what, but on "empty" pages, the sidebar doesn't get extended.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using Ajax to load content? If so, you must run the above code in the success callback instead of (or in addition to) in document.ready.

Comment: I'm not using Ajax, it's just like the fiddle. I want container to always be at least 100% height of the browser window, but when there isn't enough content to fill the page, the jQuery equal columns fail. What I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/7WraW/7/

Works when content fills it up: http://jsfiddle.net/jU7Ps/

Answer (score 0):

Here try this...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
  $('#sidebar').css('height', contentHeight + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is The jQuery plugin for equalizing the height or width of elements that's far more better and with more utilities to accomplish this, and really easy to use:

http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/

hope this helps, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple solution for equal height columns using jquery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#left_side").height($("#right_side").height());
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iyirel/1/watch